# Can i get count of $.fn.yiiListView.update in Yii?

Tags: php, yii, clistview

I want run a dual pagination for my result as it has millions of results. When I am updating the result using `$.fn.yiiListView.update`, I need count of record returned by it.

Answer (score 0):

There are **special** `$variables` in CGridView and CListView.

The **CListView** widget calls your partial rendering _view on each item, setting these variables before calling each one:

```
$data - the current object or hash being rendered
$index - the zero-based index of the item being rendered (0, 1, 2, ...)
$this - the owner of the widget, usually the calling controller
$widget - the CListView widget itself
```

The **CGridView** widget displays data in tabular form, and when each 'value' => '...' string is eval'd, these variables are available:

```
$data - the current object or hash being rendered
$row - the zero-based index of the item being rendered (0, 1, 2, ...)
$this - the CGridColumn object representing the column being rendered
$this->grid - the CGridView object that owns the column
$this->grid->owner - the owner of the grid, usually the calling controller
```

So I guess **$row** and **$index** are the variables you need. [Source.](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/252/special-variables-in-cgridview-and-clistview/)